# what is the google app engine equivalent of an nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way in google app engine where I can use a dispatch file or some other way to achieve the same result as the nginx config below ? My goal is to serve the content from the external domain as content from the same service.

````
    location /path/ {
        proxy_pass https://someexternaldomain/; 
   }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two alternatives:

**1. Coding a reverse proxy**

You can code a reverse proxy using this [tutorial](https://medium.com/customorchestrator/simple-reverse-proxy-server-using-flask-936087ce0afb) where it shows how to do it with Flask and the you can deploy it in App Engine.

**2. Using App Engine Custom Runtime**

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart):

> Custom runtimes let you build apps that run in an environment defined by a Dockerfile.

So, this means that you can run a Docker image, in particular an NGINX image and then you can load your configuration of NGINX that will let you create the reverse proxy to your external domain. You can try it using this [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) and maybe following these [tips](https://www.docker.com/blog/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/).

I think those are the best approaches for what you want to accomplish. Good luck!